# OpenCV VideoCapture fails to load compressed video files when building with staticlib

Tags: opencv, video, capture

I can embed OpenCV .DLLs and build my program in Visual Studio 2010, Debug mode, x64 platform using OpenCV 2.4.4 static libraries from C:\opencv244\build\x64\vc10\staticlib.

I use VideoCapture to load a video file and play it. Everything works fine when I open an uncompressed video file; But when I open a compressed video file (e.g. xvid), VideoCapture fails and can not load and open the video file. In this case if I put OpenCV .dll files near my program's .exe file, VideoCapture will work for the compressed video files too. But I have embedded OpenCV .dlls in the .exe file and I assume it has to be able to work fine without having OpenCV .dlls. Could you please let me know how can I resolve this issue?

Update:
Just now I noticed this issue will be resolved by only including opencv_ffmpeg244_64.dll near the program's .exe file. Other OpenCV .dlls will not be required to be present. So now the question will be: Is there any way to embed "opencv_ffmpeg244_64.dll" in the program's .exe file? (Albeith this one is not a big deal after all).